# abortHandshake(this, req, `Unexpected server response: ${res.statusCode}`);

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile, sepolia

truffle migrate --network sepolia

## Compiling your contracts...

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

/mnt/c/pr0/bootcamp-completed/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:542
abortHandshake(this, req, `Unexpected server response: ${res.statusCode}`);
^
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
at ClientRequest. (/mnt/c/pr0/bootcamp-completed/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:542:5)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:701:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

my truffle config
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

//const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey');
const privateKeys = process.env.PRIVATE_KEYS || ""

module.exports = {
networks: {
development: {
host: "127.0.0.1",
port: 7545,
network_id: "*" // Match any network id
},
goerli: {
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
privateKeys.split(','), // Array of account private keys
'wss://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/f-3RKRIsmcVn502nmzDLcXj2SOY9erRl' // URL to the Gorlan Ethereum node
),
gas:50000,
gasPrice:250000000,
network_id:5
},
sepolia: {
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
privateKeys.split(','), // Array of account private keys,
`wss://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
),
network_id: "11155111",
gas: 4465030,
gasPrice: 25000000000,
networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
timeoutBlocks: 200
},
kovan: {
provider: function() {
return new HDWalletProvider(
privateKeys.split(','), // Array of account private keys
`https://kovan.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`// Url to an Ethereum Node
)
},
gas: 5000000,
gasPrice: 25000000000,
network_id: 42
}
},
contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
compilers: {
solc: {
optimizer: {
enabled: true,
runs: 200
}
}
}
}

please help